# Linq to Sql. How to log SQL queries?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-4.8

In some point I have an instance of `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`. Here is the code:

```
using (System.Data.Linq.DataContext ctx = GetContext(...))
{
    return ctx.RoamingCountries?.ToList();
}
```

I would like to know which SQL query I will have generated by ORM.

I saw this way in the internet:

```
using (System.Data.Linq.DataContext ctx = GetContext(...))
{
    ctx.Log = Console.Out;
    return ctx.RoamingCountries?.ToList();
}
```

But I completely don't understand where I can see the result! I'm working on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 19. All debug windows keep silence.

Sorry if the question is silly. I haven't worked with .NET Framework 4.8 and Visual Studio before. Usually it's .NET Core, EF and Rider. With this stack a
queries logging is simple: add particular middleware and look at the console. But now with Linq to SQL and VS I can't figure out what I should to do to see my SQL queries.

Comment: I don't know if it is an option, but this is literally *why* we wrote `MiniProfiler`, which you can use to wrap around your underlying `DbConnection`, and it records all the SQL operations that flow through it, in an efficient way (including timings etc). Or there's SQL Profiler. Of course our next step (when we stopped crying) was to write `Dapper`, and replace huge chunks of our LINQ-to-SQL code with that. Your mileage may vary. Also; both .NET Framework and LINQ-to-SQL should be considered (picks words carefully) "complete" at this stage; you shouldn't use them for new work, ideally.